# Make AppInsights work with a NativeScript application

Tags: nativescript, appinsights

I'm trying to make a NativeScript app write logs to Azure AppInsight. I'm using npm package "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web" for that (2.5.8).

Upon the application start I'm getting this error while trying to call `new ApplicationInsights()`:

```
System.err: TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '__extends' of object '[object global]'
System.err: File: (file: node_modules\@microsoft\applicationinsights-shims\dist-esm\applicationinsights-shims.js:96:0)
System.err: 
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err: (file: node_modules\@microsoft\applicationinsights-shims\dist-esm\applicationinsights-shims.js:96:0)
System.err:     at (file: node_modules\@microsoft\applicationinsights-shims\dist-esm\applicationinsights-shims.js:97:1)
System.err:     at ../node_modules/@microsoft/applicationinsights-shims/dist-esm/applicationinsights-shims.js(file:///data/data/com.mycompany.live/files/app/vendor.js:95073:30)     
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:753:0)
System.err:     at fn(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0)
System.err:     at ../node_modules/@microsoft/applicationinsights-web/dist-esm/applicationinsights-web.js(file: node_modules\@microsoft\applicationinsights-web\dist-esm\applicationinsights-web.js:1:0)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:753:0)
System.err:     at fn(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0)
System.err:     at ./app/shared/tracking.service.ts(file:///data/data/com.mycompany.live/files/app/bundle.js:1681:92)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:753:0)
System.err:     at fn(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0)
System.err:     at ./app/shared/default-error-handler.service.ts(file:///data/data/com.mycompany.live/files/app/bundle.js:1316:75)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:753:0)
System.err:     at fn(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0)
System.err:     at ./app/shared/index.ts(file:///data/data/com.mycompany.live/files/app/bundle.js:1351:88)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:753:0)
System.err:     at fn(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0)
System.err:     at ./app/app.module.ts(file:///data/data/com.mycompany.live/files/app/bundle.js:214:66)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:753:0)
System.err:     at fn(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0)
System.err:     at (file:///data/data/com.mycompany.live/files/app/bundle.js:2027:73)
System.err:     at ./main.ts(file:///data/data/com.mycompany.live/files/app/bundle.js:2095:30)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:753:0)
System.err:     at checkDeferredModules(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:43:0)
System.err:     at webpackJsonpCallback(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:30:0)
System.err:     at (file:///data/data/com.mycompany.live/files/app/bundle.js:2:57)
System.err:     at require(:1:266)
```

I wonder if someone has already found a solution for this issue.

Comment: have you able to found any solution?

Comment: nope.https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues/1459

Comment: Dmytro  for solution you can follow this link: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues/1459#issuecomment-777992872